# c# Synchronization between 2 queue

Tags: c#, concurrency, queue, server, barrier

I'm trying to figure how to synchronize concurrent accesses to 2 related queue

I have a server, handling requests from several clients.
Those clients wants to play together (one versus one) and they will specify if they want to start first or not.
I have to handle their play request by queuing all clients, then matching them by pair (want to play first against those who don't want to play first), and let them know if any matching teammate was found

What I tryed so far :

```
internal class ClientsManager
{
    #region Members

    /// <summary>
    /// The player list.
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, DateTime> m_players = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, DateTime>();
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, TcpClientManager> m_managers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, TcpClientManager>();
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> m_duos = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

    /// <summary>
    /// The player waiting for a teammate.
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly BlockingCollection<string> m_waitingTeammate = new BlockingCollection<string>(1);
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, DateTime> m_waitingTeammates = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, DateTime>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Random number generator.
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly Random m_Random = new Random();

    /// <summary>
    /// The related <see cref="T:ArcheageServer.TcpClientManager" />.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly TcpClientManager m_clientManager;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    static ClientsManager()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(CheckPlayers, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }

    internal ClientsManager(TcpClientManager clientManager)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(clientManager != null);

        m_clientManager = clientManager;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Define the invariant valid state for this class.
    /// </summary>
    [ContractInvariantMethod]
    private void InvariantValidState()
    {
        Contract.Invariant(m_clientManager != null);
    }

    private static void CheckPlayers()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var list = m_players.Where(kvp => (DateTime.Now - kvp.Value).TotalMilliseconds > Settings.Default.ClientTimeout).ToList();
            if (list.Count > 0)
                list.ForEach(kvp => RemovePlayer(kvp.Key));
            Thread.Sleep(Settings.Default.ServerIdleTime);
        }
    }

    internal void Handle(Packet packet)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(packet != null);
        throw new NotImplementedException(String.Format("The packet Type {0} handle has not been implemented yet.", packet.GetType().ToString()));
    }

    internal void Handle(C0KeepAlivePacket c0KeepALivePacket)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(c0KeepALivePacket != null);
        UpdatePlayer(c0KeepALivePacket.PlayerName, DateTime.Now);
    }

    internal void Handle(C1WantToPlayPacket c1WantToPlayPacket)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(c1WantToPlayPacket != null);
        Contract.Assert(m_clientManager != null);

        var playerName = c1WantToPlayPacket.PlayerName;
        var waitTimeout = c1WantToPlayPacket.WaitTimeout;
        var startWaiting = DateTime.Now;
        bool shouldWait;

        UpdatePlayer(playerName, startWaiting);
        if (m_waitingTeammates.ContainsKey(playerName))
        {
            m_clientManager.Server.SendPacket(m_clientManager, new S2PlayAuthorizationPacket(true));
            return;
        }

        string teammate = null;
        while ((shouldWait = ShouldWait(playerName, startWaiting, waitTimeout)) && !FindOrWaitForTeammate(playerName, out teammate)) Thread.Sleep(10);
        if (shouldWait)
        {
            if (teammate == null)
            {
                m_waitingTeammates.AddOrUpdate(playerName, startWaiting, (name, moment) => startWaiting);

                while ((shouldWait = ShouldWait(playerName, startWaiting, waitTimeout)) && m_waitingTeammates.ContainsKey(playerName)) Thread.Sleep(10);
                if (!shouldWait)
                {
                    m_waitingTeammate.TryTake(out teammate);
                    m_waitingTeammates.TryRemove(playerName, out startWaiting);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                m_waitingTeammates.TryRemove(teammate, out startWaiting);
                m_duos.TryAdd(playerName, teammate);
                m_duos.TryAdd(teammate, playerName);
            }
        }
        m_clientManager.Server.SendPacket(m_clientManager, new S2PlayAuthorizationPacket(shouldWait));
    }

    private void UpdatePlayer(string playerName, DateTime startWaiting)
    {
        m_players.AddOrUpdate(playerName, startWaiting, (name, moment) => startWaiting);
        m_managers.AddOrUpdate(playerName, m_clientManager, (name, manager) => m_clientManager);
    }

    private static void RemovePlayer(string playerName)
    {
        string teammate;
        DateTime startWaiting;
        m_waitingTeammates.TryRemove(playerName, out startWaiting);
        m_players.TryRemove(playerName, out startWaiting);
        m_duos.TryRemove(playerName, out teammate);
        TcpClientManager tcpClientManager;
        if (m_managers.TryRemove(teammate, out tcpClientManager))
            tcpClientManager.Server.SendPacket(tcpClientManager, new S6StopPlayPacket());
        m_managers.TryRemove(playerName, out tcpClientManager);
        m_duos.TryRemove(teammate, out playerName);
    }

    private bool FindOrWaitForTeammate(string playerName, out string teammate)
    {
        teammate = null;
        return m_waitingTeammate.TryAdd(playerName) || m_waitingTeammate.TryTake(out teammate);
    }

    private static bool ShouldWait(string playerName, DateTime startWaiting, int waitTimeout)
    {
        return m_players.ContainsKey(playerName) && (DateTime.Now - startWaiting).TotalMilliseconds < waitTimeout;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I've try with the barrier class without more success :

```
    private static Barrier m_waitFirsts = new Barrier(1, (b) =>
    {
        while (m_goFirsts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("wait winners");
            m_wait.SignalAndWait();
            Console.WriteLine("winners waited");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("winners false");
        m_goFirsts = false;
    });
    private static Barrier m_waitLoosers = new Barrier(1, (b) =>
    {
        while (m_goSeconds)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("wait loosers");
            m_wait.SignalAndWait();
            Console.WriteLine("loosers waited");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("m_goLoosers false");
        m_goSeconds = false;
    });
    private static Barrier m_wait = new Barrier(2, (b) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("m_go false");
        m_go = false;
    });

    private static bool m_goFirsts = true;
    private static bool m_goSeconds = true;
    private static bool m_go = true;

    internal void Handle(C1WantToPlayPacket c1WantToPlayPacket)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(c1WantToPlayPacket.ToString());
        while (m_go)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c1WantToPlayPacket.PlayerName);
            if ((c1WantToPlayPacket.IsWinner ? m_waitFirsts : m_waitLoosers).SignalAndWait(c1WantToPlayPacket.WaitTimeout))
                Console.WriteLine(c1WantToPlayPacket.PlayerName + " YES");
            else
                Console.WriteLine(c1WantToPlayPacket.PlayerName + " NO");
        }
    }
```

It was easy to block until 2 players are found, then continue, but could not handle the specific case of 1 first and 1 second player...

Am I missing a simple way to do it with any of the framework class ?
My code seems ugly as hell and I have to maintain a lot of concurrent collections to achieve a simple task

Comment: Can you give specifics as to what is wrong with the code you currently have?

Comment: the code with barrier does not works at all
the initial code lacks when it comes to concurrency : 
- players A comes, wait for another player
- Player B comes just when player A timeout exprire
- player B get a positive nswer, player a a negative answer
- game is launch with only playerB

I have anoher problems like that, I think my code is not optimised enogh to handle concurrency

It was easy to code with only a pending players list, but now that I have to differentiate the 2 kinds of players, I'm stuck :s

Comment: To summarize my problem, I want to take 1 element per 1 element from 2 distinct queue and create tuple with them, given the queue item have timers and must be removed when this timer is up